# OpenGL Texture Mapping using .jpg texture file

Tags: xcode, opengl, texture-mapping, libjpeg

Does anyone know whether or not XCode has a framework (library) for reading and writing jpeg files, and what is the library/framework name? I want to load this jpg image for a texture mapping in OpenGL.
If you have done texture mapping using jpg image, do you mind to share the code as well?
I found a good example here, however it is using a .raw file instead of .jpg file. Of course the open gl codes would be the same. Only the image loader function would be different.
http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SOIL](http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html).  Its a header file that can load JPG (and most other image formats).

Its used by lots of real games.